# Spinner not getting selected value

Tags: android

I am have 2 spinners that are set to initial values. I then expect the user to select new values. I am then trying to get those values. However, `getSelectedItem()` only returns the initial value - the change is not saved, even though the new selection shows up in the spinner:

```
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.lessonTypeSpinner);
        Spinner weatherConditionS = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.weatherConditionSpinner);
        spinner1.setSelection(hmlessonType.get(lessonType));
        weatherConditionS.setSelection(hmWeatherCondition.get(weatherCondition));
        Button update = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.updateButton);

        final String lessonTypeCopy = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        final String weatherConditionCopy = weatherConditionS.getSelectedItem().toString();

        pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(this.PREF_FILENAME, 0);
        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
                edit.putString("lessonType", lessonTypeCopy);
                edit.putString("weatherCondition", weatherConditionCopy);
                edit.apply();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the values inside onClick() method.
You should change it like this:

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.lessonTypeSpinner);
    Spinner weatherConditionS = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.weatherConditionSpinner);
    spinner1.setSelection(hmlessonType.get(lessonType));
    weatherConditionS.setSelection(hmWeatherCondition.get(weatherCondition));
    Button update = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.updateButton);

    pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(this.PREF_FILENAME, 0);
    update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String lessonTypeCopy = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            final String weatherConditionCopy = weatherConditionS.getSelectedItem().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
            edit.putString("lessonType", lessonTypeCopy);
            edit.putString("weatherCondition", weatherConditionCopy);
            edit.apply();
        }
    });
```